# How to know if a certain future is complete by avoiding a chain of future as return types?

Tags: dart

**Scenario**

If I want to read from a file and store the data in a Map, and if that map is being used multiple times for validation.

Is it possible for me to do this without having to change the return type of all methods, that use the above mentioned map, to Future?

Example:

```
Map metadata = null
Future readFromFile async {
 .... metadata = await File.readingfromFile(...);
}

Future getRegion(..) async {
  if(metadata == null) { await readFromFile() }
  return metadata["region"]
}
```

Using the above code if a method(like isValidRegion,etc) that uses and needs getRegion(..) to complete, then the return type of isValidRegion should be converted to Future.

```
Future<bool> isValidRegion(..) async {
   return ((await getRegionData(...)) != null )
}
```

If that isValidRegion is present within another methods, then the return type of them have to be changed to Future as well.

```
Future<String> parse(...) async {
   ....
   if(await isValidRegion()) {
    ...
    }
...
}
```

What is an elegant way to avoid this chain of futures as return types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Async execution is contagious, there is nothing you can do to get back from async to sync execution.

What you can do is to do the read from the file synchronous to avoid the problem in the first place (if this is possible, if you read it from a network connection, this might not be possible).

Comment: There's a great article by Bob Nystrom about the contagiousness of async: http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/. In other words, yes, this is a problem, and there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for replies. 
I wonder on how other major libraries handle reading from files and avoid the contagiousness. I might have to search for one and investigate it.